# Implementing alpha for the HMM algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I'm working on implementing HMM Forward Algorithm in Matlab. I am having some difficulty in coding the $\alpha_{j}(t)$

1. **initialize** $t <- ,$ $a_{ij}, b_{jk}$, visible sequence $V^T, \alpha_j(0)$
2. for $t <- t + 1$
3. $\alpha_{j}(t) <-$   $  \sum^c_{1 = 1}  \alpha_i(t - 1) a_{ij}b_{jk} v(t)$
4. until $t = T$
5. **return** $P(V^T) <- \alpha_0(T)$ for the final state
6. **end**

How would I implement the calculation for $\alpha_{j}(t)$. when $ a_{ij} = $ the transition probability matrix & $ b_{jk} =$ the emission matrix & $ v(t) = $ the observed symbols

Comment: `TeX` syntax is not supported here on SO.

Comment: Understood is it not legible like this should I change it so i can get an answer to my question